# How to merge two streams and emit them simultaneously using StreamBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make 2 simultaneous queries to Firebase and then stream their results as a single stream, emitting their results one at a time as they come through.

I've tried using this code below, but only one of the stream seems to work, even when both streams should have a result.

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot> searchQuery(String searchQuery) {
    final firstStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collectionGroup("newProduct")
        .where('sWords', arrayContains: searchQuery)
        .snapshots();

    final secondStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collectionGroup("usedProduct")
        .where("sWords", arrayContains: searchQuery)
        .snapshots();

    final mergedStream = Rx.merge([firstStream, secondStream]);

    return mergedStream;
  }
```

This is the StreamBuilder where I'm making use of the merged stream

```
StreamBuilder(
          stream: _marketDatabaseService.searchQuery(_searchQuery),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text("An error has occurred!");
            } else if (snapshot.hasData &&
                snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
              List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> querySnapshot =
                  snapshot.data.documents;

              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: querySnapshot.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return Text(querySnapshot[index]["prN"]);
                  });
            } else {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                ),
              );
            }
          },
        ),
```

Note: I'm making use of rxdart package in this example.

Comment: You might want to use [`StreamGroup`](https://pub.dev/documentation/async/latest/async/StreamGroup-class.html) from `package:async`.

Comment: I've actually solved the problem using a StreamZip. Could you give me an example of how to use a StreamGroup to achieve my desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To query 2 collections in Firebase, use the following code snippet:

```
Stream<List<QuerySnapshot>> getData(String searchQuery) {
    Stream stream1 = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collectionGroup('newProdut')
        .where('sWords', arrayContains: searchQuery)
        .snapshots();
    Stream stream2 = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collectionGroup('usedProduct')
        .where('sWords', arrayContains: searchQuery)
        .snapshots();
    return StreamZip([stream1, stream2]);
  }
```

Then in your StreamBuilder Widget you the following code snippet to output the data:

```
     StreamBuilder(
            stream: getData(_searchQuery),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text("An error has occurred!");
              } else if (snapshot.hasData &&
                  snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {

                List<QuerySnapshot> querySnapshot = snapshot.data.toList();

                List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> documentSnapshot = [];

                querySnapshot.forEach((query) {
                   documentSnapshot.addAll(query.docs);
                });

                /// This "mappedData" will contain contents from both streams
                List<Map<String, dynamic>> mappedData = [];

                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc in documentSnapshot) {
                    mappedData.add(doc.data());
                }

                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: mappedData.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Text(mappedData[index]["prN"]);
                    });
              } else {
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                );
              }
            },
          ),
```

Comment: What is StreamZip?